# Read inserted row (one db connection, autocommited queries) failed in Galera cluster

Tags: mysql, galera

I'm using Galera cluster (mariadb 10.2, 2 nodes + garb, master-master) and I have noticed that in some cases (bigger load) fetching row, which was inserted right before read, fails. It's during one db connection to one cluster node, so it should not be affected by replication latency.

It's rare, but it happens sometimes during bigger load and more concurrent connections which are writing to same db table.

All queries are sent in autocommit mode, so without explicit transaction. But it's the same in case that insert is done in explicit transaction and fetch in autocmmited query I'm using mysql PDO from PHP script.

Queries could by e.g. like:

```
-- insert into table
INSERT INTO t ...;
-- fetch id of inserted row to variable
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- fetch row by id
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=$id;
-- -> no row found
```

Plase, any ideas where is a problem and what cause this behavior?

Comment: Is there a load balancer or proxy involved?

Comment: Yes, there is used haproxy. But haproxy should load balance whole db connections to db nodes. It does not spread queries.

Comment: Hmmm... If those three statements were sent through the _same_ connection, then there _should not_ be a problem.  If putting `BEGIN`..`COMMIT` around that code solves the problem, file a bug with Galera.